# Reading multithread data with OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, multithreading, oledbdatareader

I'm trying to read data from sql server by using OleDbDataReader in a web service as can be seen below:

```
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
List<JPH> returnList = new List<JPH>();
while (reader.Read())
{
    JPH item = new JPH();`

    DateTime tmp = DBTypesEvaluator.ToDateTime(reader["POSITIONDATE"]);
    item.t = Functions.GetTimeFullStringSepFormat(tmp);

    item.lC = DBTypesEvaluator.ToString(reader["LOCATION"]);
    item.lT = DBTypesEvaluator.ToFloat(reader["LATITUDE"]);
    item.lN = DBTypesEvaluator.ToFloat(reader["LONGITUDE"]);
    item.iG = DBTypesEvaluator.ToInteger(reader["IGNITION"]);
    item.sP = DBTypesEvaluator.ToInteger(reader["SPEED"]);
    item.oD = Functions.RoundToDigits( DBTypesEvaluator.ToFloat(reader["ODOMETER"]));
    item.tF = Functions.RoundToDigits( DBTypesEvaluator.ToFloat(reader["TOTALFUEL"]));
    item.fL = DBTypesEvaluator.ToString(reader["FUELLEVEL"]);

    returnList.Add(item);
}
connection.Close();
return returnList;
```

Although the query result returns quickly, because of while loop, it takes too long to return from service.

To solve this problem, i tried to use OleDbAdapter and DataSet like this:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

By using OleDbAdapter and DataSet, i divided data into parts and processed them by multithread.
But, in this time, Fill function took long time again. 
As a result, is there a way to read data from query by multithread in .net? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268075/making-datasets-thread-safe-in-c-sharp help?

Comment: DataReaders are the fastest data access technology available in .NET, so switching to datasets will only make it slower. How many records do you fetch here? What is the database engine?

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 2014 standart edition (version: 12.0.4237.0) and the problem is occured after 5000 records.